# Should I use symlinks in /usr/bin or use the PATH variable instead?

Tags: path, directory-structure

I was looking to download some tool and it said to update your PATH variable, but I thought `/usr/bin` was the "standard".

Comment: Does the tool work with the symlinks?

Comment: If it's a local install, the standard location would be `/usr/local/bin`. Let the OS vendor handle `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not too uncommon to have tools that expect to be installed at user level.  As such, they will not assume that you can modify anything directly under `/usr`.  It is often common, however, to have a `~/bin` or `~/usr/bin` directory where you can include symlinks to tools that you have installed for your user.  Such that you don't have to constantly update a `$PATH` variable.

Comment: in my noobness I think I mistook ~/usr/bin for /usr/bin.  THAT makes sense!

Comment: To be fair, I don't think there is a "set in stone" answer for this.  I, personally, leave `/usr/bin` and friends alone.  The package managers and everyone involved with that fun can take over those directories.  The more adventuresome/knowledgeable folks out there are free to do whatever you want.  If you find something that works really well, share it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes feel that it is more efficient to add a symlink from /usr/bin (or /bin or /usr/sbin or one of the friends) to wherever the application installed put the programs, rather than to add the program to a PATH definition.

Advantages:

1. Don't need to update PATH settings in potentially a plethora of places.
2. Fewer directories to search.

Disadvantages:

1. This makes for a non-standard installation, which means you need to
   consider the impact on things like updates and re-installation,
   particularly when those may be carried out on people other than
   yourself.

The program will work the same whether its directory is added to the PATH, the files are copied into a directory already part of the PATH, or symlinked from an included directory to the directory where it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu ~/.profile includes:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```